# Python Syntax error on anaconda def __init__(self, pad_result: tuple = None, width=0, height=0): invalid syntax

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, anaconda, syntax-error

I am trying to run a code which had the following requirements that are already installed:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1 ,scipy==1.0.0, opencv-python==3.3.0.10, numpy==1.11.0, Pillow==5.1.0, CUDA 8.0, Cudnn 6.0
```

```
def __init__(self, pad_result: tuple = None, width=0, height=0):
```

and I get an invalid syntax error
I am running using anaconda and I tried a couple of different python versions(2.7 , 3.6 ...) Is there a specific version to use or is it another problem?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem with python 3.7.7

Comment: Can you share the full error please.

Comment: If that's the line reported by the traceback, the error likely occurs on an earlier line.

Answer (score 0):

This Python code is for Python 3.5 or newer, because there are [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html). Given that you're using a fairly old version of numpy (2016) I suspect that you're using a pre-3.5 Python interpreter as well.

Anaconda can be weird about changing the version of the Python interpreter. Double-check by

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```